# How can I convert HTML to markdown?

Tags: php, html, markdown

I have a website like stackoverflow. There is a textarea which people write answers. I use [this PHP library](http://parsedown.org/) to convert markdown. I mean I use that function to convert `*italic*` to `<i>italic</i>`.

```
// include that library
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();
echo $Parsedown->text('*italic*'); # prints: <i>italic</i>
```

Well All fine. It should be noted I convert that answer (to html tags, not markdown symbols) befor storing, in other word, all data in the database are containing HTML tags, not markdown symbols.

Now I want to implement *Editing-System* for answers. Something exactly like stackoverflow. So I need to convert saved answer to markdown-style again.

Now I want to know, how can I reconvert it? I mean I want to convert `<i>italic</i>` to `*italic*`, How can I do that?

Comment: which parser? several have a 'revese' function

Comment: @Dagon [This parser](http://parsedown.org/) ..! Has it a reverse function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any PHP markdown reverse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072169/is-there-any-php-markdown-reverse)

Answer (score 8):

Rather than storing the original input as *parsed* markdown, you should store the actual markdown and convert it to HTML only when rendering it to the page.

This way you retain the original markdown for editing as required. It is also more logical.

Comment: Was in the process of saving both versions before I saw your answer and was like dah!

Answer (score 6):

I needed this too, I found these 2 github projects:

- https://github.com/Elephant418/Markdownify
- https://github.com/thephpleague/html-to-markdown

I used the first one, because it has support for Markdown Extra (converted with ParsedownExtra), and it worked well for me.